# syntax error near unexpected token `done' in bash code

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, restart

I am looking for some working shell code for auto restart mysql servers if it is not working. here are some code witch i foound in google search, listen 3306 port, if it is not working, restart. if can not restart, reboot the server.

Can this code work? If not, is anyone can share me a working code? If yes, i met `syntax error near unexpected token`done' in bash code`, how to solve it? thanks.

```
PORT=`netstat -na|grep "LISTEN"|grep "3306"|awk -F[:" "]+ '{print $5}'`
MYSQLIP=`ifconfig eth0|awk '/inet/{print $2}'|cut -c 6-`
while [ `whoami` == "root" ]
do
  if [ "$PORT" == "3306" ];then
    echo "mysql is running......"
  else
    service mysql restart
       if [ "$PORT" == "3306" ];then
       else
           reboot
       fi
  fi
break
done
```

Modify code:

```
PORT=`netstat -na|grep "LISTEN"|grep "3306"|awk -F[:" "]+ '{print $5}'`
MYSQLIP=`ifconfig eth0|awk '/inet/{print $2}'|cut -c 6-`
while [ `whoami` == "root" ]
do
  if [ "$PORT" == "3306" ];then
    echo "mysql is running......"
  else
    service mysql restart
       if [ "$PORT" == "3306" ];then
         :
       else
           reboot
       fi
  fi
break
done
```

Comment: I think rebooting the box if mysql does not start is a very bad idea. For example, if there is any typo in my.cnf that will cause mysql to fail to start, you now have a box rebooting in a loop.

Comment: @Marc Alff, if the my.cnf config well, my sys has run for few months, but sometimes the mysql was crashed, can not restart in ssh part, only reboot can recover the system. so it is still a bad idea? it is impossible monitor my site in 24 hours, thanks for discuss.

Comment: Just pointing out possible risks. You can also use mysqld_safe, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition test must execute some sort of code if true.

It looks like you want to `reboot` if `"$PORT"` is not `"3306"`.

You should only use `break` when testing a condition, otherwise the loop will only execute once.

The `PORT` variable will not update unless you call the code that sets it again after you need it to update.

Also, you don't need to use `grep` when you are using `awk`.

```
#!/bin/bash

callport ()
{
    PORT=`netstat -na|awk -F[:" "]+ '/LISTEN/ && /3306/ {print $5}'`
}
MYSQLIP=`ifconfig eth0|awk '/inet/{print $2}'|cut -c 6-`
while [ `whoami` == "root" ]
do
  callport
  if [ "$PORT" == "3306" ];then
    echo "mysql is running......"
    break
  else
    service mysql restart
    callport
       if [ "$PORT" != "3306" ];then
           reboot
       fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: hello, reboot is a bad idea? line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `
line 1: `callport (), i edit in dreamweaver. thanks.

Comment: do you have `#!/bin/bash` shebang at the start of the script?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this script but it doesn't seem like a `reboot` would solve anything that restarting the `mysql` service won't do.

Comment: yes, i add it at the top of all ,still line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ` line 1: `callport (),